# How to show that $E([X|Y])^{2} = E[X^{2}|Y]$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-probability, variance

I have some isssue with this equation:
$$
\mathrm{var}[X|Y] = E([X|Y])^{2} - (E[X|Y])^{2} 
$$
How to show that
$
E([X|Y])^{2} = E[X^{2}|Y]
$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You don't need to show anything:
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X\mid Y)\equiv\mathsf{E}[X^2\mid Y]-(\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y])^2.
$$

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes, but how?

Comment: @Blabla How what?

Comment: @d.k.o. It is by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have some isssue with this equation: $$var[X|Y] = E([X|Y])^{2} - (E[X|Y])^{2} $$

The conditional variance of $X$ measured against $Y$ is by definition:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(X\mid Y)&=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X\mid Y))^2\mid Y)\\&=\mathsf E(X^2-2X\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y)+\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2\mid Y)\\&=\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y)-2\,\mathsf E(X\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y)\mid Y)+\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2\mid Y)\\&=\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y)-2\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2+\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2\\&=\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y)-\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2\end{align}$$

> How to show that $E([X|Y])^{2} = E[X^{2}|Y]$?

You generally *do not*, as it requires $\mathsf{Var}(X\mid Y)=0$, which is to say that $X$ is completely determined by $Y$ (ie there is *no unexplained variance*).